# Windows 10 global proxy software that allows private/public key authentication

Tags: networking, proxy, ssh-tunnel

We have a SSH jump server at work, which I need to tunnel all my specific application trafic through. I have some code that targets a machine that my network can't access, so I need to tunnel my trafic through our jump server.

I've looked at a bunch of different ways, including Proxifier and `netsh`, but as far as I can see, none of them support private/public key authentication. Pretty bummer, as I need to use that.

What other software is there, that allows me to do that? Proxifier looks great, but it doesn't have key authentication, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Do you mean, software which can force programs to use an SSH tunnel even if they don't support SOCKS proxy built-in? Otherwise just the standard SSH client features are sufficient...

Comment: @grawity Exactly. I could use regular Putty, which does work as far as I know, but not everything is SOCKS supported

Comment: Do you just need a few specific hosts? Have you tried using the static "local" tunnels instead?

Comment: @grawity A few specific hosts? I just need my machine to target one hostname outside my network. And no, I have not. How does that work? I just need to be able to send HTTP requests from my local Visual Studio .NET project to the hostname outside my network

Comment: @MortenMoulder That's easy with PuTTY: **Connection > SSH > Tunnel** - **_Source Port_:** arbitrary port on host PC _(say `10123`)_ **_Destination_:** VS `IP:port` _(say `192.168.1.2:80`)_ > **Add**.  With that session open, direct traffic to `http://127.0.0.1:10123`.  I don't want to create this as an answer because it was @grawity who suggested it.

Comment: @JW0914 Let's say my source port is 10123. My jump server is jump.domain.com. The website that I can't access from my local network is logs.domain.com:1234 - How would I set that up in Putty? jump.domain.com has network connectivity with logs.domain.com

Comment: @MortenMoulder grawity may need to answer that, as I've only ever used an IP, not a DNS domain.   You should be able to get the domain's IP via `nslookup jump.domain.com` (in Windows, not sure about Linux).

Comment: @JW0914 I'm using Windows. I can get the IP no problem, but I don't understand the destination port. What's the port on the jump server?

Comment: @MortenMoulder Destination Port would be the port Visual Studio is accepting HTTP requests on.  Essentially all you're doing is mapping an arbitrary local port on `localhost` to an IP and port combination on a remote device, allowing you access to the remote device via `localhost:10123` || `127.0.0.1:10123`

Comment: @JW0914 At what point in this process, do I specify I want to use the jump server and the unreachable host? My Visual Studio project connects to logs.domain.com on port 10123. If I simply point my local port 10123 to jump.domain.com:10123, I have never specified I want to do anything with logs.domain.com. If I do this, connect via Putty (SSH I assume), I get into the jump.domain.com server. I can type any Linux command I want. If I go to logs.domain.com:10123 in my browser, I get a timeout. If I put "127.0.0.1 logs.domain.com" into my hosts file, I get Connection Reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101021/discussion-between-jw0914-and-mortenmoulder).